# How to use python regular expression inside if... else... statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My Python script:

```
import wget

if windowsbit == x86:
    url = 'http://test.com/test_windows_2_56_30-STEST.exe'
    filename = wget.download(url)
else:
    url = 'http://test.com/test_windows-x64_2_56_30-STEST.exe'
    filename = wget.download(url)
```

In above python script, I am using `wget` module to download a file form URL, based on windows 32 bit or 64 bit. Its working as expected.

I want to use regular expression to do the following:

if `windowsbit == x86`, its should download the file that starting with `test_windows` and ends with `STEST.exe` file.
else its should download file that starting with `test_windows-x64` and ends with `STEST.exe` file.

I am new to python, I not getting any idea on how to do this. Could any one guide me on this?

Comment: When you say it is working, do you mean that your conditions are working, but the file is not downloading?

Comment: @idjaw I mean, am able to download the file, condition is working. But I want to put the regexp, so that if version number change in future , my script can handle this.

Comment: This doesn't look like a regular expression problem. You don't appear to have a way to query the webserver to find the link to the "newest" version (as indicated in your comment), and you can't use a regular expression as a wildcard like you might in a shell script (e.g. `mv *.jpg images/`).

Comment: @Adam Smith. Is there a way to tell to download a latest version of particular file in python?

Comment: You should consider something like: `filename = "STEST.exe"; cur_version = "2_56_30"; base_url = "http://test.com/test_windows"; if windowsbit == x64: base_url += "-x64"; final_url = "{base}_{version}-{filename}".format(base=base_url, version=cur_version, filename=filename)`

Comment: @Kumar There's no general way of downloading a latest version of something *at all*. How would Python (or anything else?) know what the latest version is, or how/where it would be found? There may be a specific way for **this file**, if the authors have created some API to allow that lookup.

Comment: is it possible to put starts with and endswith in URL?

Comment: @Kumar you can certainly TEST to see if a string ends with a certain character. What you seem to be suggesting is to somehow make the web server do that for you when you request the data. That's not possible (unless the author has created a way for you to do that, e.g. some symlink to `http://test.com/test_windows-x64_latest-STEST.exe` or etc)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look possible. The regular expression that would match what you're trying to do is something like:

```
import re

urlre = re.compile("""
    http://test.com/test_windows    # base URL
    (?P<bit>-x64)?                  # captures -x64 if present
    _(?P<version_major>\d+)         # captures major version
    _(?P<version_minor>\d+)         # captures minor version
    _(?P<version_revision>\d+)      # captures revision version
    -STEST.exe                      # ending filename""", re.X)
```

However you can't just throw that in `wget`. You can't use wildcards in requests -- the webserver would have to know how to process them and it doesn't. A better method might be:

```
base_url = "http://test.com/test_windows"
if windowsbit == x64:
    base_url += "-x64"
version = "2_56_30"
filename = "STEST.exe"

final_url = "{base}_{version}-{filename}".format(
    base=base_url, version=version, filename=filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Take that url contains only two files. one is for 32 bit and another is for 64 bit. I mean always the old files with be deleted and only new files will be there in that url. Always 32 bit file will start with test_windows and ends with STEST.exe . And 64bit file will start with test_windows-x64 and ends with STEST.exe . in this case we can use regexp right?

Comment: @Kumar then your new question should be "How do I ask the webserver if a file exists based on a wildcard"

Comment: Thanks I will add the new question as you said . Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

May be try this without regular expression:

```
import wget

text ="http://test.com/test_windows"

if windowsbit == x86:
    url = '{}_2_56_30-STEST.exe'.format(text)
else:
    url = '{}-x64_2_56_30-STEST.exe'.format(text)
filename = wget.download(url)
```

With version:

```
import wget

text ="http://test.com/test_windows"
version = '2_56_30'

if windowsbit == x86:
    url = '{}_{}-STEST.exe'.format(text,version)
else:
    url = '{}-x64_{}-STEST.exe'.format(text,version)
filename = wget.download(url)
```

Comment: The OP's problem comes from trying to account for newer version releases.

Comment: @Randomazer. Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to keep "version = '2_56_30'" as optional. Since it wont be always fixed number. it will keep changing.