# How do I ask the webserver if a file exists based on a wildcard

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the continuation of question

> [How to use python regular expression inside if... else... statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800464/how-to-use-python-regular-expression-inside-if-else-statement/32800731?noredirect=1#comment53438838_32800731)

My Python script:

```
import wget

if windowsbit == x86:
    url = 'http://test.com/test_windows_2_56_30-STEST.exe'
    filename = wget.download(url)
else:
    url = 'http://test.com/test_windows-x64_2_56_30-STEST.exe'
    filename = wget.download(url)
```

url contains only two files. one is for 32 bit and another is for 64 bit. I mean always the old files with be deleted and only new files will be there in that url. Always 32 bit file will start with test_windows and ends with STEST.exe . And 64bit file will start with test_windows-x64 and ends with STEST.exe .

Could anyone guide me on writing wildcard or regexp?

Comment: what are you checking the url or filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the url and it is always in that format, you just need to check if it startswith `"test_windows-x64"` after splitting:

```
if url.rsplit("/", 1)[1].startswith("test_windows-x64"): 
           # do whatever
else:
    # it is 32 bit
```

If you really need to check the ending:

```
base = url.rsplit(None,1)[1]
if base.startswith("test_windows-x64") and base.endswith("STEST.exe")
```